# configuring my java EE project in intelij with wildfly

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, artifact

I am trying to figure what configuration I should have for my Java EE project so that I can run it inside IntelliJ and instead of packaging with maven and uploading my **war** file manually, I want to use WildFly plugin to do that inside the IntelliJ for me.

My project is empty and I initially uploaded the **war** file into deployments in WildFly manually.

For configuring inside IntelliJ I selected a JBoss server configuration. I have a problem with choosing an artifact here. If the artifact tab is empty, my changes will not show when I run this configuration. 
(my IntelliJ is the ultimate version)

What should I do so that I don't need to run

```
    mvn package
```

before building my configuration

Comment: If you are using the wildfly maven plugin to deploy the war, you might just need to bind to the install phase or change your ide to run the install goal of that plugin

Comment: Can I ask what plugin this is?
I've installed maven and wildfly and defined a configuration for my project. The configuration is a JBoss server.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin name is wildfly-maven-plugin. You can find more details in below link
https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html